# Using code signing private key to encrypt in PHP, need to decrypt in C# using public key

Tags: c#, php, encryption, certificate

I have written a method which uses my private key ([thawte states](https://www.thawte.com/resources/getting-started/how-code-signing-works/) that the private key is not to be distributed. Signing happens using the private key, and embeds the public key into the file for verifying the signing).

Following is the PHP code I am using to encrypt (which I can decrypt using my public key in PHP successfully)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo decode(sign("hello world"));

function sign($data) {
    $k = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents("key.pem"));
    $ret = "";
    $output = "";
    try{
        if( openssl_private_encrypt( $data, $output, $k ) ) {
            $ret = base64_encode($output);
        } else {
            $ret = "Failed";
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $ret = "Failed:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $ret;
}


function decode($data) {
    $k = openssl_get_publickey(file_get_contents("public.cer"));
    $ret = "";
    $output = "";
    try{
        if( openssl_public_decrypt( base64_decode($data), $output, $k  ) ) {
            $ret = $output;
        } else {
            $ret = "Failed";
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $ret = "Failed:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

I have also tried using the library available here [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) which claims to be a pure PHP method for encryption, using the following code to create the encrypted data :

```
include('Math/BigInteger.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

echo sign2("Hello World");

function sign2($data) {
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    extract($rsa->createKey());
    $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents("key.pem"));
    $ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($data);
    return base64_encode($ciphertext);
}
```

Here is what I have so far in C#, but it is causing an exception on `rsa.DecryptValue()`

```
    public string Decrypt( string Key, string Data ) {
        X509Certificate2 cert=new X509Certificate2( Key, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable );
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa=cert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
        return GetString( rsa.DecryptValue( Convert.FromBase64String( Data ) ) );
    }

    static string GetString( byte[] bytes ) {
        char[] chars=new char[bytes.Length/sizeof( char )];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy( bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length );
        return new string( chars );
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the error I am receiving:

[image: Key does not exist]

So I attempted to try something a bit more complex using code obtained from [Extracting Modules and Component(RSAParameter) from X509Certificate PublicKey](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kishorerc/RSapParameter11232005061709AM/RSapParameter.aspx) in an attempt to fill the RSAParameter with needed modulus/etc to complete the decryption ......  it still fails.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


namespace TestCase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    public class TestCase
    {
        public static void Main(string[] certfilex)
        {
            string[] certfile = { @"D:\Server\www\127.0.0.1\htdocs\sign\public.cer" };
            string enc = ""; // Base64 encoded string is here, but removed for posting on SO
            if (certfile == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate filename is not valid");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            try
            {
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(certfile[0]));
                byte[] buf = new byte[br.BaseStream.Length];
                br.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(buf);

                RSAParameters p = X509PublicKeyParser.GetRSAPublicKeyParameters(cert);
                X509Certificate2 crt=new X509Certificate2( certfile[0], "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable );
                using ( RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa=crt.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider ) {
                    rsa.ImportParameters(p);
                    byte[] unb64 = Convert.FromBase64String(enc);
//                  Array.Reverse(unb64);
                    try {
                        byte[] results=rsa.Decrypt( unb64, false );
                        Console.WriteLine( GetString( results ) );
                    } catch ( CryptographicException ce ) {
                        Console.WriteLine(ce.Message);
                    }
                }

//                HexDump("Modulus:", p.Modulus);
//                HexDump("Exponent:", p.Exponent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " \r\n " + e.StackTrace);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static byte[] GetBytes( string str ) {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[str.Length*sizeof( char )];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy( str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length );
            return bytes;
        }

        static string GetString( byte[] bytes ) {
            char[] chars=new char[bytes.Length/sizeof( char )];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy( bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length );
            return new string( chars );
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Converts and writes the bytes as hexadecimal values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="label">Dump header</param>
        /// <param name="ba">value to be printed</param>
        public static void HexDump(string label, byte[] ba)
        {
            const string SPC = " ";
            string tid = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
            if (ba == null)
            {
                ba = new byte[0];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(label + " [" + tid + "], " + ba.Length);
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            string LINE_SEP = Environment.NewLine;
            for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && (i % 16) == 0)
                {
                    buf.Append(LINE_SEP);
                }
                if (i % 8 == 0)
                {
                    buf.Append(SPC);
                }
                string str = Convert.ToString(ba[i], 16);
                if (str.Trim().Length == 1)
                {
                    str = "0" + str.Trim();
                }
                buf.Append(str + SPC);
            }
            if (ba.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(buf.ToString().ToUpper());
            }
        }

    }



    internal class IntegerContainer : AbstractAsn1Container { internal IntegerContainer( byte[] abyte, int i ) : base( abyte, i, 0x2 ) { } }
    internal class SequenceContainer : AbstractAsn1Container { internal SequenceContainer( byte[] abyte, int i ) : base( abyte, i, 0x30 ) { } }

    public class X509PublicKeyParser
    {
        public static RSAParameters GetRSAPublicKeyParameters(byte[] bytes) { return GetRSAPublicKeyParameters(bytes, 0); }

        public static RSAParameters GetRSAPublicKeyParameters(byte[] bytes, int i) {
            SequenceContainer seq = new SequenceContainer(bytes, i);
            IntegerContainer modContainer = new IntegerContainer(seq.Bytes, 0);
            IntegerContainer expContainer = new IntegerContainer(seq.Bytes, modContainer.Offset);
            return LoadKeyData(modContainer.Bytes, 0, modContainer.Bytes.Length, expContainer.Bytes, 0, expContainer.Bytes.Length);
        }

        public static RSAParameters GetRSAPublicKeyParameters(X509Certificate cert) { return GetRSAPublicKeyParameters(cert.GetPublicKey(), 0); }

        private static RSAParameters LoadKeyData(byte[] abyte0, int i, int j, byte[] abyte1, int k, int l) {
            byte[] modulus = null;
            byte[] publicExponent = null;
            for(; abyte0[i] == 0; i++)
                j--;

            modulus = new byte[j];
            Array.Copy(abyte0, i, modulus, 0, j);
            int i1 = modulus.Length * 8;
            int j1 = modulus[0] & 0xff;
            for(int k1 = j1 & 0x80; k1 == 0; k1 = j1 << 1 & 0xff)
                i1--;

            if(i1 < 256 || i1 > 2048)
                throw new X509ParserException("Invalid RSA modulus size.");
            for(; abyte1[k] == 0; k++)
                l--;

            publicExponent = new byte[l];
            Array.Copy(abyte1, k, publicExponent, 0, l);
            RSAParameters p = new RSAParameters();
            p.Modulus = modulus;
            p.Exponent = publicExponent; 
            return p;
        }
    }

    public class X509ParserException : SystemException {
        public X509ParserException() : base() { }
        public X509ParserException( string msg ) : base( msg ) { }
        public X509ParserException( string msg, Exception e ) : base( msg, e ) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AbstractAsn1Container.
    /// </summary>
    internal abstract class AbstractAsn1Container {
        private int offset;
        private byte[] data;
        private byte tag;

        internal protected AbstractAsn1Container( byte[] abyte, int i, byte tag ) {
            this.tag=tag;
            if ( abyte[i]!=tag ) {
                throw new X509ParserException( "Invalid data. The tag byte is not valid" );
            }
            int length=DetermineLength( abyte, i+1 );
            int bytesInLengthField=DetermineLengthLen( abyte, i+1 );
            int start=i+bytesInLengthField+1;
            this.offset=start+length;
            data=new byte[length];
            Array.Copy( abyte, start, data, 0, length );
        }

        internal int Offset {
            get {
                return offset;
            }
        }

        internal byte[] Bytes {
            get {
                return this.data;
            }
        }

        internal protected virtual int DetermineLengthLen( byte[] abyte0, int i ) {
            int j=abyte0[i]&0xff;
            switch ( j ) {
                case 129:
                    return 2;

                case 130:
                    return 3;

                case 131:
                    return 4;

                case 132:
                    return 5;

                case 128:
                default:
                    return 1;
            }
        }

        internal protected virtual int DetermineLength( byte[] abyte0, int i ) {
            int j=abyte0[i]&0xff;
            switch ( j ) {
                case 128:
                    return DetermineIndefiniteLength( abyte0, i );

                case 129:
                    return abyte0[i+1]&0xff;

                case 130:
                    int k=( abyte0[i+1]&0xff )<<8;
                    k|=abyte0[i+2]&0xff;
                    return k;

                case 131:
                    int l=( abyte0[i+1]&0xff )<<16;
                    l|=( abyte0[i+2]&0xff )<<8;
                    l|=abyte0[i+3]&0xff;
                    return l;
            }
            return j;
        }

        internal protected virtual int DetermineIndefiniteLength( byte[] abyte0, int i ) {
            if ( ( abyte0[i-1]&0xff&0x20 )==0 )
                throw new X509ParserException( "Invalid indefinite length." );
            int j=0;
            int k;
            int l;
            for ( i++; abyte0[i]!=0&&abyte0[i+1]!=0; i+=1+k+l ) {
                j++;
                k=DetermineLengthLen( abyte0, i+1 );
                j+=k;
                l=DetermineLength( abyte0, i+1 );
                j+=l;
            }

            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like, is to do the equivalent to the above decode method, but in C#. I have seen someone spam their response across the internet (including on StackOverflow), however their claim of "it's not possible", is not logical or valid.

I am looking for a serious well thought answer to this. From what I have tested, loading the certificate/etc isn't that complex, it's more just finding the right combination of commands for the task.

Thanks in advance.

(Adding a note that I am not looking for use of 3rd party libraries. This is feasable using .NET framework only.)

Comment: phpseclib uses OAEP mode for encryption by default. It's more secure than the alternative of PKCS1 mode but it's also less commonly used. To use PKCS1 mode do `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);` before `$rsa->encrypt()`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually doing here is verifying and recovering a short signed message - this won't work on messages much larger than 200 bytes since it's using the RSA key pair directly.

**EDIT**: this may work.  I didn't know about `PublicKey.Key` doing the parameter-shoveling work for you, so I was busy writing a screen full of byte-bashing nastiness.  You don't need the bytes-to-string conversion code either.  To my utter astonishment, the final result actually comes out shorter. :-)

```
public string Decrypt( string Key, string Data ) {
    var cert = new X509Certificate2( Key );
    var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) cert.PublicKey.Key;
    return Encoding.Default.GetString( rsa.Decrypt( Convert.FromBase64String( Data ), false ) );
}
```

As an aside, I highly recommend C-style casting instead of `as` in this case, since it throws `InvalidCastException` promptly at the operator if the cast fails.  `as`-casts silently return `null`, causing the next line to throw a `NullReferenceException` instead.

---

I can offer a variation that uses the [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) library, since it provides a generous API surface including some OpenSSL-like capabilities.

```
using System.IO;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

internal class Example
{
    internal static string Decode(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            X509Certificate k;

            // read in the certificate
            using (var textReader = File.OpenText("public.cer"))
            {
                // I'm assuming here that the certificate is PEM-encoded.
                var pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
                k = (X509Certificate)pemReader.ReadObject();
            }

            // un-base64 the input
            var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            // what php openssl_public_decrypt does
            var cipher = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
            cipher.Init(false, k.GetPublicKey());
            var returnBytes = cipher.ProcessBlock(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);

            // What is the character-encoding of the bytes? UTF-8?
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Failed:" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please do this without bouncy castle.

Comment: I updated my post to include what I have partially working so far in C#. The certificate is loading fine, but I think something is being lost in the translation.  All of the certificate details seem to be in place when inspecting `rsa` after loading the x509 cert.

Comment: @SanuelJackson, since `System.Security.Cryptography` doesn't publicly surface a means to grab the key out of a certificate in a form you can plug into `RSAParameters`, you end up with nasty glob of glue code to unpack the binary key substructure -- or not, if you can find the right combination of properties...

Comment: I am ok with a nasty glob of glue code if thats required.  I did try this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847743/using-an-rsa-public-key-to-decrypt-a-string-that-was-encrypted-using-rsa-private  << but the `glue` is incorrect.

Comment: I was trying to write a cleaner version of that glueball until you surprised me with `cert.PublicKey.Key` :)

Comment: Hehehe, where it seems to be dorking is the params are not being set it seems (modulus, exponent, etc etc ... all the junk in RSAParameters .

Comment: The code you added, shows the same problem I am having. Will give a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Here is the screenshot > http://i.imgur.com/kWquO3M.png <  also adding to main post.  I was thinking that should be that easy as well, but it doesn't parse out whats needed to decrypt properly or something.

Comment: Added some more use/case scenarios and tests that I attempted including using a "pure" php lib to do full RSA encoding, and a .NET class designed to extract the modulus/etc to `RSAParameters` ... still buggered.

Comment: I think `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is hard-coded to only use private keys in `Decrypt`; to go the opposite direction it wants you to encrypt the hash of your data rather than the data directly, and use [`VerifyData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55yk5665(v=vs.90).aspx) (or [`VerifyHash`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash(v=vs.90).aspx)) to test for equality of the decrypted hash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77760/discussion-between-jeffrey-hantin-and-sanuel-jackson).

Comment: This is just silliness.  There must be a way to encrypt using private certificate, using public to decrypt.  A one-way hash is useless for what I intend to do ....  and having a reversable encryption method using the same password, is just silly as that would require embedding the password to decrypt which was used to encrypt in the .NET compile which is (insert fecal matter word here) as it no longer offers the protection that 'old' languages like even VB6 compiled code offered due to exposing everything, forced to use shoddy obfuscation instead of real protection -.-

Comment: The restriction is probably because `RSACryptoServiceProvider` isn't always pure software, it may also wrap a hardware crypto device that enforces this behavior.  The RSA decrypt is trivial to code once you've broken the key apart into exponent and modulus anyway - stuff the encrypted data, exponent and modulus into positive [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) values (note: you may have to reverse the byte arrays), take `BigInteger.ModPow(encryptedData, exponent, modulus).ToByteArray()`, and reverse it again.

Comment: I did notice that, but some of the examples on obtaining modulus + exponent from the cipher seem a bit off, either wrong, or literally the modulus is every so many bytes or something like that.  Not sure how to reliably get the modulus and exponent,  plus seems there are several other pieces required such as the D, and Q values.  Modulus and exponent also seem to be byte arrays.  Will try to frankenstein that line of code you wrote above into it and see if some magic happens

Comment: Try `ExportParameters(false)` on `PublicKey.Key` to obtain the exponent and modulus values.

Comment: Well, it seems we are getting closer.  When I try Decrypt or DecryptValue after using ExportParameters(false) and importing,  I get 'Method not supported' on Decrypt.

Comment: Could you provide a sample on how you see this working please.  It looks like we are on the right track, but I am unsure how to push the string into a BigInt, and same with other byte arrays for modulus, and exponent.

Comment: `System.Security.Cryptography` appears to be hardcoded to prevent you from decrypting with a public key.  The idea here is to `ExportParameters` to get the individual variables from the key, then forget about the standard library and reimplement everything else.  For what it's worth, that's why I suggested Bouncy Castle in the first place: it doesn't try to prevent you from using components in a nonstandard manner (and won't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot either).

Comment: the exportparameters, i am not sure if the values are correct since when i do ModPow, even reversing some or all,  appending 0 to force positive or not, the resulting char array is not the decrypted values which is why I was asking if you could throw up how to do this.  The math looks correct, however something is off,  not sure how to get the exponent /etc used in php to decode -- and i should be getting that from the certificate for sure right ?

Comment: The `Exponent` and `Modulus` from the certificate should both be in the `RSAParameters` structure returned by `ExportParameters`.  I'm not precisely sure what formatting is applied to the byte arrays returned, though.

Comment: Thats where I am getting stumped.  I feel we are making good headway here, and the ModPow thing, seems logical.  I am using the values from RSAParameters, but it doesn't take into account padding / etc.  I am just unsure as to what to do with the bytes following ModPow(), or if I need to pre-process them somehow ---  or do i do them one by one. ModPow expects a big integer, and it doesn't seem right to force the value to be positive ... just have no idea here XD

Comment: After ModPow, the byte array needs to be put back in big-endian order.  Assuming you unwound the RSA correctly, you have zero-padding, old-school PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP "padding" (masking, really; OAEP is a two-step Feistel network) to remove.  Zero-padding and PKCS#1 padding is just that, padding, and your original message bytes would be present in the output, while OAEP-masked data looks like line noise.

Comment: Marking as complete.  Still need some help with this tho.  Would be cool if you could provide an example on how to unwrap / etc.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I edited your solution with the correct answer to this which doesn't depend on 3rd party libraries.  The above solution works and includes example usage.  As you may note, some of the solution was derived from your comments and a tonne of outside research. Thank you for giving me the idea to reverse using BigInteger.  The result is this is not possible using System.Cryptography alone, which is sad, but at least there is a solution now for those who need it, and you will get the credit for it.

Comment: If you can pastebin your working version somewhere I'll see if I can integrate it.  Alternatively, you can add an answer your own question.