# What algorithm should I use for sign jwt

Tags: algorithm, security, cookies, jwt

[jwt.io](http://jwt.io) referred that there are many algorithms, which are:

> `HS256` `HS384` `HS512`
>
> `RS256` `RS384` `RS512`
>
> `ES256` `ES384` `ES512`
>
> `PS256` `PS384` `PS512`

my question is what are the differences between these algorithms? And what is the most secure one? And if I am going to store the jwt in cookies what algorithm should I use?

Comment: For anyone else finding this question, I suggest... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588319/understanding-rsa-signing-for-jwt/51912247#51912247