# Base64 encode/decode in ECC encrypt and decrypt

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, spongycastle

I want to test the ECC algorithm encrypt and decrypt.

I write code to:

- Generate key pair (publickey and privatekey) ---> write them to file (maybe not secure but I just only test).
- Then using public key to encrypt my string (Write on Java)
- Now, I take the encrypted string and try to decrypt it on Android (Using private key)

Here is my code:

1. Encrypt string in Java:

   ```
   /// generate key pair
   ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime256v1");
   try 
   {
       KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
       g.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
       KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();
       privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
       publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
       System.out.println("PublicKey:"+publicKey+"\n");
       System.out.println("PrivateKey:"+privateKey+"\n");

   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
    try {
       Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
       c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
       encodeBytes = c.doFinal(origin.getBytes());
       String encrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodeBytes);
       System.out.println(encrypt);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

My output encrypt string like this:

```
BB9Y4sKPbp28y7+FnpGnLGz5aTjD58GiIcXgjnNC4nXlUiqlHVVPc4K+ovlK5HK+Hz1Qps4ZWH9VdoYvm6VE36aEqvy53lJFnANDVpqAKuDUUaqEUrIQgF/TXFCFO22Il411atDsNhvJC3eRXbREL14duQbF8xjnLjru6WLN6GDYAQ==
```

And here is my private key

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgCybVICafKcZiEmGNw+Pj/FfL6GMgDc94/E0zJ/EKgdGgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAATRTcV/M0OJE94qlZM7VksMOw35fcuGSxejdgzbyYllWtlIQw9gYhKPZx6t/PVOEOec4DyZq2XwaoNxBxWRboL1
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

2. Decrypt string on Android

   ```
   encodeBytes = Base64.decode(encrypted_string_above,Base64.DEFAULT);
   try
           {
               KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");

               String state;
               state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
               File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
               File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/disk");
               privateKeyFromFile = generatePrivateKey(factory,dir+"/private.pem");

               Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES","SC");
               c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKeyFromFile);
               decodeBytes = c.doFinal(encodeBytes);
               String deCrypt = new String(decodeBytes,"UTF-8");


               txtHiden.setText(deCrypt);
               Toast.makeText(activity, deCrypt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
   ```

But my code not success decrypt, it have a problem:

```
  10-03 00:52:18.264 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err: org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to process block
  10-03 00:52:18.264 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.IESCipher.engineDoFinal(IESCipher.java:476)
  10-03 00:52:18.264 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
  10-03 00:52:18.264 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at com.example.napoleon.luanvana.MessageFragment$3.onClick(MessageFragment.java:156)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err: Caused by: org.spongycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: unable to recover ephemeral public key: Sender's public key has invalid point encoding 0x51
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.IESEngine.processBlock(IESEngine.java:409)
  10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.IESCipher.engineDoFinal(IESCipher.java:472)
 10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     ... 12 more
 10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sender's public key has invalid point encoding 0x51
 10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.crypto.parsers.ECIESPublicKeyParser.readKey(ECIESPublicKeyParser.java:46)
 10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.IESEngine.processBlock(IESEngine.java:405)
 10-03 00:52:18.265 28656-28656/com.example.napoleon.luanvana W/System.err:     ... 13 more
```

I think it maybe cause by wrong encode/decode string - byte - Base64

```
(Enctypt side)String encrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodeBytes);
(Decrypt side): encodeBytes = Base64.decode(encrypted_string_above,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But I do not have much experience in this problem.

Comment: The statck trace point to an IO Exception : Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sender's public key has invalid point encoding 0x51

Comment: Also you seem to be using ECDSA as the key gen alogorithm. ----KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA",B) -----ECDSA is a digital signature algo where you use the private key to sign and public key to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ECIE scheme you should be using ECDH as the alogorithm to generate key pair for encryption/decryption and not ECDSA as the later is a digital signature algorithm.

```
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, i will check it. And accept your answer if it work :D

Comment: You are right, I must use ECDH, but I don't know why can't use ECDSA, both of them generate key pair.

Comment: Well both generate key pairs but there is a fundemental difference between how the keys are used for encryption/decryption and signing. You need to do a bit of reading and researching , can start here (talks about RSA though): ------https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454048/what-is-the-difference-between-encrypting-and-signing-in-asymmetric-encryption