# RSA Private key encrypt QT C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, encryption, rsa

My question is about RSA Private Encrypt, not just about signing. And yes, I understand the differences between signing, private-key encryption and public-key encryption.

Now I need to encrypt using the private RSA key and decrypt using the public key.
Not vice versa, and not signing.

So, my question is not about whether can I encrypt with the private key, it's about QT libraries, that can do this.

Need to use it with `QT` windows.

Keys in PEM format `(base64)`

Comment: This isn't possible using standard public/private key crytography. You may be confusing it with digital signing. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454048/what-is-the-difference-between-encrypting-and-signing-in-asymmetric-encryption

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between encrypting and signing in asymmetric encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454048/what-is-the-difference-between-encrypting-and-signing-in-asymmetric-encryption)

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: NO! I no need just signing, I need to encrypt by private key. Signing is another function.

Comment: @psy21d one does not encrypt with the private key.  That's not the way the algorithm has been designed.  You encrypt with the public, and decrypt  with the private.

Comment: @UKMonkey Why it is not designed? At all? In any libraries?

Comment: not at all, anywhere.  Read the duplicate link!

Comment: Because everyone has your public key (it's public) everyone can read your message if you encrypt it with your private key.  So there is no point in encrypting the whole message (with your private key) just to prove you were the sender.

Comment: @Richard Critten yes I understand that fact. But I need this way.

Comment: @Mat I just look any library that do what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not openssl?

```
int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
int RSA_private_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
int RSA_private_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa,int padding);
int RSA_public_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, 
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa,int padding);
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it!