# Unable to understand PKI concept in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am just starting Hyperledger Fabric. I was reading about PKI concept in Hyperledger fabric.I am reading form this [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/identity/identity.html)

Below is the diagram they explain Marry uses her private key to sign the document. But in general its is explain in this [link](https://www.comodo.com/resources/small-business/digital-certificates2.php)

that public key is used for encryption.

So which key is used for encryption ?

[image]

Comment: Its signing vs. encryption. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454048/what-is-the-difference-between-encrypting-and-signing-in-asymmetric-encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various aspects to Asymmetric Cryptography. A confidential message can be encrypted and disseminated over the network in various ways. Let's assume there are two participants in the network - A and B, each of them have registered themselves with a certificate authority and have obtained their crypto pair - a public key and a private key. Now, if A wants to send a message to B, he has two options

1. encrypt the message M using his private key and send. Now, if B has
   access to A's public key over the network, he will be able to
   decrypt the message. Now, assuming A's public key is generally
   available over the consortium network, people other than B also will
   have access to A's public key. Now, does this compromise the message
   integrity? Well, no. This is because the encryption is a function of
   the private key as well as the message, so people having the right
   access can decrypt and see the message but will not be able to
   tamper it unless A's private key is compromised.
2. Another way in which A can send message to B, is by encrypting it
   with B's public key. Now, this message can only be decrypted only by
   B and whoever B chooses to share his private key with in a secure
   manner. Here, again the encryption will be a function of B's public
   key and the message - that said the integrity of message can be
   assured.

Hyperledger Fabric follows the first method - the messages are encrypted by sender's private key and recipient's access to the sender's public key or to the message per say is managed by by consortium/organization's membership, access control rules and channel policies.