# How does differ openssl signing and encrypting programmatically

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

There is this question on SO:

[What is the difference between encrypting and signing in asymmetric encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454048/what-is-the-difference-between-encrypting-and-signing-in-asymmetric-encryption)

My question is not a duplicate. I am asking if there is difference between two programmatically.

I have an openssl C++ API to sign and verify a message. Let say two functions:

**sign**

**verify**

Let say two sides who interchange messages are **A** and **B**.

Currenlty sign function uses **A_privateKey**, and verify function uses **B_publicKey**.

Now, I want to encrypt some part of the message.

So, could I do it just using **sign** function with **B_publicKey**?

Or the algorithm to encrypt is totally different and I need to implement a new function?

Or with some modification in **sign** function (removing generating hash, for ex) does it just work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Now, I want to encrypt some part of the message.
So, could I do it just using sign function with B_publicKey?
```

The output of the **sign** function is an encrypted **hash** of the original message. If "A" were to tranmit the output of **sign** as you describe, the only thing B could do is decrypt it back to the hash of the original message. **He wouldn't have the actual message.**

Because assymetric encryption can be a very computationally expensive operation that doesn't scale well for long messages, the standard pattern is this:

- Alice generates a message she wants to send to Bob.
- Alice generates a **symmetric key** first
- Alice encrypts the message with this symmetric key.
- Alice encrypts the symmetric key with Bob's public key
- Alice transmits the encrypted message and encrypted key to Bob.

Then Bob does this:

- Bob receives both the message that was symmetrically encrypted and
  the assymetrically encrypted key.
- Bob decrypts the symmetric key with his public key
- Bob uses the symmetric key to decrypt the encrypted message

There's probably a ton of other security principals missing as well, but the above is the general idea.

Comment: Actually, because of the hash, I had asked what would happen if we remove the hash part from sign function, ie, signing directly the message but not the hash, even though it is computationally expensive. What would be that output? Encrypted message?

Comment: From a public/private key perspective, it's the equivalent of full encryption. Not sure if OpenSSL can do a public key encryption on a full message without generating a key first.  Not sure if "signing" also decorates the message with additional meta and headers.